# ruby Inject a keystroke in windows shell

Tags: ruby, windows, shell

IS there a way in ruby I can inject a keystroke in shell to have the program go? I need to run a program in shell through

```
sh " #{another program}"
```

And there is a 
"Press any key to continue" at the end of the program. How can I make it move on ?

Is there something similar in ruby like java

http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke

Comment: Look for an 'expect' equivalent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142978/is-there-an-expect-equivalent-gem-for-ruby

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is with Autoit, it can be controlled through the COM interface like this

```
require 'win32ole'
ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
ai.WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
1.upto(10) do |i|
  ai.Send "#{i}{ENTER}"
end
```

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'WIN32OLE' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: win32-file, win32ole-pp, win32olerot, win32rc, windoze

Comment: use it on multiple vista an win7 boxes, no problem, win32ole is in the standard libray, no gem required, autoix needs to be installed so that the COM object is avaiable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Open3.popen2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2) to start the process and get handles to stdout and stdin, and then you should be able to "press a key" by doing `stdin.puts "Y"`.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.
 Try Console.Read.

Comment: Okay, now you're confusing me a bit. Are you running inside IronRuby or JRuby or something? `System.InvalidOperationException` sounds like a .NET thing. The ruby implementation you're using is very important, because I doubt the Open3 library is going to run correctly in IronRuby.

Comment: It is the exception of the .Net programming I was running, not ruby itself.

Comment: Apparently the .NET program doesn't like redirected console input and is expecting actual keypresses; my program would only work if the spawned code was using Console.Read. I'm not sure how to support this scenario from Ruby!