# Sending remote commands with Plink

Tags: serial-port, putty, plink

I am trying to automate sending remote commands/getting responses to a linux host with plink/putty through a serial connection. I can successfully establish the connection:

```
plink.exe -load "COM4"
```

But how can I add my commands to the above?What I am looking for is something similar to:

```
plink.exe -load "COM4" <command> <parameter -1> <parameter-2> ...
```

I have already tried:

```
plink.exe -load "COM4" echo <command>
plink.exe -load "COM4" <command>
```

and they don't seem to work! Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: There's no mention of you not wanting to use a file, in your question. If you have such constraint, you have to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool that will spawn the serial comms app as a subprocess and then pipe your input/outputs to it.

'Expect' is used for controlling command line tools in this way and comes in various flavours:

- Original [TCL Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).
- [Python Expect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [Perl Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod)
- Even Ruby has [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142978/is-there-an-expect-equivalent-gem-for-ruby)