# Can I programmatically interact with an "installer" (ie. ./install.sh)

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, terminal, network-programming

I need to run a fairly complicated `installer.sh` script that, when ran, asks you all kinds of questions via `dialog` command which involve typing, multiple choice, checkboxes.

I need to run this installer on many, many, many machines. I'm trying to think of a way to write a simple `ruby` script to SSH into a server, run the command, but then use code to programmatically answer the questions when "prompted". I would write/handle what answers to put in my ruby code.

Is this possible?

The only caveat I can think of is it does 4 minutes of installing before asking for prompts. Ideally the script could detect 'am I being prompted?' and then answer right away so my ruby code would be systematic like...

```
1. <up><enter>
2. password<enter>
3. <space><enter>
```

I am also open to other methods of doing it...

I can't really "unwrap" the installer as it is just so complicated, I really just have to go through the prompts.

I have thought about provisioning images like in AWS... but the host I must use does not support images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142978/is-there-an-expect-equivalent-gem-for-ruby

Comment: Ruby has limited support for Expect-like interactions via the pty and open3 modules, but using Expect directly or via scripts and  system commands is often more powerful.